# Simple HTML/PHP form takes forever to send email

Tags: php, html, forms, mailto

I have this simple email form using the POST function with a PHP mailto() function. I have PHP lines within my form as values to the fields. It takes way too long to send. Any help is appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $error="<br/>-Please enter your name";
    }
        if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error.="<br/>-Please enter your email";
    }
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $error.="<br/>-Please enter a message";
    }
        if (!$_POST['check']) {
        $error.="<br/>-Please confirm you're real";
    }

    if ($error){
        $result="Ohh no, somethings not right... $error";
    }
    else {

        mail("email@email.com","website contact form","Name: ".$_POST['name']."
            Email: ".$_POST['email']."
            Message: ".$_POST['message']);

        {
            $result="Thank you, I will reply shortly.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#contactme" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="<? echo $_POST['name']; ?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="<? echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message..."><? echo $_POST['message']; ?> </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check"><span class="real"> I am real</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Remember all the PHP `mail()` function does is pass your mail to a mail server. Its the mail server that does all the actual sending of the email. That process will involve virus checking etc and will probably not be sending just your email.

Comment: Then when the email gets sent from your mail server the receiving mail server has to redo the virus checking etc etc and then you will be allowed to see it. Also if you are using a mail client which will only check for email every X minutes that also adds time to the process

Comment: You need to use `filter_input()`. Also checkboxes can be filled out by bots.

Comment: Also you'll want to strip out any BCC or CC's as well from the input. This way your script isn't used to mass mail people with a bot.

Comment: PHP's mailto() function is actually quite slow. One way to speed it up is to output the "thank you" page before you call the mailto(), that way the users notice it less. Another is to store the message and run a cron job to send out the emails.

Answer (score 0):

I have done everything in a query now it should be sent faster but it can also be that this code has an error but the first query is correct from the structure.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if (!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['message'] || !$_POST['check'] ||) {
        $error="<br/>-Please enter";
    }else
{

 if ($error){
        $result="Ohh no, somethings not right... $error";
    }
    else {

        mail("email@email.com","website contact form","Name: ".$_POST['name']."
            Email: ".$_POST['email']."
            Message: ".$_POST['message']);

        {
            $result="Thank you, I will reply shortly.";
        }
    } <-- If you have a mistake, take a clip away.


}


}
?>
```